# How to understand what type was selected instead of T in generic method?

Tags: java, generics, type-conversion, wildcard, type-inference

please research following code snippet:

```
class Ideone {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        List<Integer> listIntegers = null;
        List<Object> listObjects = null;
        MyClass mcls =new MyClass ();

        SomeReference ref = mcls.method(listIntegers,listObjects));//which SomeReference may be?
    }
}

class MyClass {
    <T> T  method(List<? extends T> arg1, List<? super T> arg2) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

What can I write in return statement of method with name `method` except `null`;

Object?
Number?
Integer?

Comment: What you want to return? What is your expected output?

Comment: @Braj I am confusing what can I return. I want to know all possible variants

Comment: If don't know what you want to do then first think about it and ask again. Even you don't know what this method is doing here then how  come you can expect from us to think about it. **Never** ask any such stupid question that is even not clear to you itself.

Comment: I want to write something like this: **Reference ref =mcls.method(listIntegers,listObjects)**

Comment: Look you are passing two list and just returning only one item. But not clear to me how are you using these list in the method and what you want to return. Make it more clear, Please....

Comment: I just try to deal with the theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might help you to understand it. Since you can't return any item from the second list so there is only one option to return item from first list.

```
class MyClass {
    <T> T method(List<? extends T> list1, List<? super T> list2) {
        return list1.get(0); // Valid
        //return list2.get(0); // Invalid Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? super T to T
    }
}

List<Integer> listIntegers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
listIntegers.add(1);

List<String> listObjects = new ArrayList<String>();
listObjects.add("2");

MyClass mcls = new MyClass();

// Valid
Integer result=mcls.method(listIntegers, listObjects);

// Invalid
String result=mcls.method(listIntegers, listObjects);
// The method method(List<? extends T>, List<? super T>) in the type MyClass is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>, List<String>)
```

Comment: Thus is T most specific type?

Comment: If you think that you will pass two different type of list in this method then use double generic parameters `<T,V>`

Comment: it is only teoretical question